# Annoying yfinance error and incompatibility with numpy/pandas

Tags: python, numpy, yfinance

I have the latest numpy and pandas installed and yfinance too, since I just installed them recently. (like a couple of days ago)
Now right now I am getting the error:

TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type

My Code literally is:

```
    stock = yf.Ticker('MSFT')
```

Thank you

Comment: Please update your post with your versions of `pd.__version__`, `np.__version__` and `yf.__version__`

Answer (score 1):

For this versions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

print(pd.__version__)
# Output: 1.3.3

print(np.__version__)
# Output: 1.21.2

print(yf.__version__)
# Output: 0.1.63
```

The code below works:

```
stock = yf.Ticker('MSFT')
print(stock.actions)

# Output:
            Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                               
1987-09-21       0.00           2.0
1990-04-16       0.00           2.0
1991-06-27       0.00           1.5
1992-06-15       0.00           1.5
1994-05-23       0.00           2.0
...               ...           ...
2020-08-19       0.51           0.0
2020-11-18       0.56           0.0
2021-02-17       0.56           0.0
2021-05-19       0.56           0.0
2021-08-18       0.56           0.0

[80 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: yep I had to downgrade my np version from 1.3 to 1.21

Comment: Are you sure to 'downgrade'? `numpy==1.3` is a old release. The latest version of `numpy==1.21`. Do you mean 'upgrade'?